# Помогите с wordpress не добавляет свойство

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'wp_nav_menu' ) ) { // Added in 3.0 ?>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'container' => false,
        'menu_id' => 'dropmenu',
        'fallback_cb' => 'revert_wp_menu_page',
        'menu_class' => 'nav nav-justified'
    )); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
```

Не добавляет nav nav-justified

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, потому что у вас чуть выше задано`'container' => false`

> container(строка) - чем оборачивать ul тег. Допустимо: div или nav. Если не нужно оборачивать ничем, то пишем false (container => false).
>   (c) [wp-kama.ru](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu)